# Parsing arbitrary number of arguments in Python OptParser

Tags: python, command-line, optparse

How can I define an option with an arbitrary number of arguments in Python's OptParser?

I'd like something like:

```
python my_program.py --my-option X,Y  # one argument passed, "X,Y"

python my_prgoram.py --my-option X,Y  Z,W  # two arguments passed, "X,Y" and "Z,W"
```

the nargs= option of OptParser limits me to a defined number.  How can I do something like this?

```
parser.add_option("--my-options", dest="my_options", action="append", nargs="*")
```

which will simply take whatever's after --my-option and put it into a list?  E.g. for case 1, it should be ["X,Y"], for case 2 it should be ["X,Y", "Z,W"].

What's a way to do this with OptParser?

thanks.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025214.

Answer (score 3):

The optarse module is deprecated in python 2.7 (which has just been released!). If you can upgrade, then you can use its replacement the argparse module. I think that has what you want. It supports a `'*'` value for `nargs`.

http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#nargs

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ommitting the n_args bit? The [examples in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#default-values) suggest you don't need it.